# Laos citizen to holiday in Australia

Tags: visas, australia, scams, laotian-citizens

What would my friend need to visit Australia? He is  a Lao citizen and passport holder but has been told he needs to pay$600 for a land lease check. It seems a bit excessive.

Comment: He's told about the money by whom?

Comment: How well do you know this person?